# How do you register for UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification in MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have a problem that the ViewWillAppear method for a UIView does not fire when the application returns from the background. This is a problem, as my main application screen is showing values that are retrieved from the user settings, and if the user has changed these while the application was in the background I need to have the screen refreshed. I have read that one should register for the UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification using NSNotificationCenter.

How do you do this in MonoTouch? Or does anyone know an alternate way of ensuring that the screen is always kept up to date, even when returning from the background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of:

```
//Register for the notification somewhere in the app
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.WillEnterForegroundNotification, EnteredForeground);

//snip

void EnteredForeground (NSNotification notification)
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Bear in mind you would need to do this for every view controller you'd like to update when enterting from the background!

Comment: Thanks, Luke. It is a bit of a nuisance that the ViewWillAppear does not fire in the case of the application returning from the background. But I will try the solution you propose here. Thanks.

Comment: Luke, is it good design to use NSNotificationCenter here? Wouldn't it be better to override the corresponding method in AppDelegate and then handle the updating from there? Or is the argument that NSNotifiactionCenters allows loose coupling?

Comment: I assume you should call the corresponding RemoveObserver as well when your view is finished. In my UIViewController I've done it in ViewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappear, which for all their faults do appear to be called reliably and symmetrically.