# MonoTouch: How to update a view

Tags: xamarin.ios

My app captures some information(timestamp, timer) when application goes in background and becomes active again. Once App becomes active again, i want to update that information on the view. I get a control over the app using

```
public override void WillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)
{
      // Here i calculate few thing and i want to update that value on a different screen 
     // which will get called next.
  }
```

How can i set values of varibes from different screen?

Thank you

Comment: Check out this other thread/discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967232/how-do-you-register-for-uiapplicationwillenterforegroundnotification-in-monotouc

Comment: do you want to know how to refresh the View, or how to get data captured in one View available in a 2nd View?

Comment: @Jason: In my case, i want to update a view when user comes back to the app. I followed Bens link and it worked.