# Xamarin iOS ViewDidAppear is not called when opening app from background

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am new to mobile development. I would like to show a different screen if GPS is not enabled. I have put the code in the view did appear to show the new screen this works most of the time. However when app returns from background the new screen is not shown.  After debugging i found that when the app returns to foreground Viewdidload/viewdidappear/the constructor of the controller is not called.

Is there an override which I can use to when the app returns from background on the controller. Also after research I found this link

[My Research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864364/viewdidappear-is-not-called-when-opening-app-from-background)

If this is the way forward, can someone help me convert this code to Xamarin ios.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Natively you'd listen for `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`. Not sure how it works in Xamarin.

Comment: @GuyKogus 's solution will work for you..

Comment: Thank you.  But I am not sure how to do it in xamarin. Will be good to have some code example.

Comment: Trying to use the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967232/how-do-you-register-for-uiapplicationwillenterforegroundnotification-in-monotouc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you register for UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification in MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967232/how-do-you-register-for-uiapplicationwillenterforegroundnotification-in-monotouc)

Answer (score 1):

In **Xamarin IOS** , adding Notifications in `ViewDidLoad` Method , can do that in `ViewDidAppear`.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
     base.ViewDidLoad ();

     UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveWillEnterForeground ((sender, args) => {
         Console.WriteLine("Welcome back!");
         //Add code from ViewDidAppear method here
     });
}
```

Here is the [IOS LifeCycle document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo#walkthrough)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use default notification center and then call your `ViewModel` methods.

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIScene.WillEnterForegroundNotification,
                notification =>
                {
                    ViewModel.ViewAppearing();
                });
```

**Bonus:**

If you'll put this code in `ViewDidLoad` then it will add multiple observers which will cause the observer to trigger multiple times.
Save `NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver` return token and then in `ViewWillDisappear` you can just dispose the token. It will now not called multiple times now.